# How to solve a complex equation with sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm using sympy to solve a  complex Linear equation, but the running time is too long.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sympy import Symbol, solve, solveset, S
return_issuedate = Symbol("x")
cf = [0.002475, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 1.01215]
dates= [0.030555555555555555, 0.2833333333333333, 0.5333333333333333, 0.7888888888888889, 1.0444444444444445, 1.2972222222222223, 1.5472222222222223, 1.8027777777777778, 2.058333333333333, 2.311111111111111, 2.563888888888889, 2.8194444444444446, 3.075, 3.225]
def fuc():
    pv = 0
    for i in range(len(dates)):
        pv += cf[i] / ((1.0348 + return_issuedate)**dates[i])
    return pv
y = pv-1
solve(pv, return_issuedate)
def fuc(x):
    Fuc = 0.906388368761923*(0.966357479077276*x + 1)**(-3.225) + 0.0182273612116527*(0.966357479077276*x + 1)**(-3.075) + 0.0183874673568639*(0.966357479077276*x + 1)**(-2.81944444444444) + 0.0185489798481412*(0.966357479077276*x + 1)**(-2.56388888888889) + 0.0187101323765637*(0.966357479077276*x + 1)**(-2.31111111111111) + 0.0188726849893914*(0.966357479077276*x + 1)**(-2.05833333333333) + 0.0190384595526071*(0.966357479077276*x + 1)**(-1.80277777777778) + 0.019205690252341*(0.966357479077276*x + 1)**(-1.54722222222222) + 0.0193707067861002*(0.966357479077276*x + 1)**(-1.29722222222222) + 0.0195389984334829*(0.966357479077276*x + 1)**(-1.04444444444444) + 0.0197106257844827*(0.966357479077276*x + 1)**(-0.788888888888889) + 0.0198837606819267*(0.966357479077276*x + 1)**(-0.533333333333333) + 0.0200546032407058*(0.966357479077276*x + 1)**(-0.283333333333333) + 0.00247241335529259*(0.966357479077276*x + 1)**(-0.0305555555555556) - 1
    return Fuc

print(scipy.optimize.fsolve(fuc,0))
```

What should I do to get the solution of this equation quickly?
How should I define my function?

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is too complicated to be solved symbolically. It is certainly not linear as suggested in the question post. For convenience, sympy also supports a numerical solver, `nsolve`. [`nsolve`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html) needs an initial value as its third parameter.

Note that in your test code, `pv` isn't really calculated, and `-1` isn't taken into account in the call to `solve`. `Eq(lhs, rhs)` creates an equation (here this is equivalent to the expression `lhs-rhs == 0`).

```py
from sympy import Symbol, Eq, nsolve

return_issuedate = Symbol("x")
cf = [0.002475, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 0.02025, 1.01215]
dates = [0.030555555555555555, 0.2833333333333333, 0.5333333333333333, 0.7888888888888889, 1.0444444444444445, 1.2972222222222223, 1.5472222222222223, 1.8027777777777778, 2.058333333333333, 2.311111111111111, 2.563888888888889, 2.8194444444444446, 3.075, 3.225]

pv = sum([cf_i / ((1.0348 + return_issuedate) ** date_i) for cf_i, date_i in zip(cf, dates)])

res = nsolve(Eq(pv, 1), return_issuedate, 0)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
0.0475300665272506
```